# Abbreviated core workout routine

Tags: core, high-intensity

I am looking for a very abbreviated (3-4 sets per week, to failure) core workout routine. I have access to free  weights and not much else. I can deadlift (within reason - see background) and I don't have a squat rack. I like "push yourself, go one more inch" type of workouts because of my personality. Any ideas?

Background:
44 years old male, white collar worker, high stress job/short on time. I have a pile of weights in the corner of my house and I lift them for one set in the morning and one set in the evening, both to failure. I also have two high energy dogs, I walk/bike/jog slowly with them for about 1.5 hours per day (less than an hour a day of activity my German Shepherd gets aggressive). I hike occasionally.

Comment: In fitness, "core" workout usually means a workout for your abdominals. But from your description seems like that's not what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: I mean a workout for the kind of muscles you use to move the whole upper torso relative to the hips (bend over and lift when wrestling, turn into the punch when boxing etc). Abs are definitely included, I am not sure what else is included. I would count the lower back too, it does the same jobs as the abs except in the opposite direction (bending forward vs bending backward). I am looking for real life strength/endurance not bodybuilding.

Comment: It sounds like you'd be interested in CrossFit (functional, timed, stress-relief, push yourself).

Comment: I am not interested in Crossfit because I have my dogs :-) Between sweating in a gym and running with my dogs in a park one is distinctly more fun for me.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with your core workout? There are some good reasons to work out your core, but your comment suggests you are doing it while short on time to become stronger, maybe your average wellness core workout for moms is not the most efficient use of your time then. The core workout is one of those things that is done way too much, perhaps because people want visible abs and you can do it while lying on the floor watching tv, perhaps because of burning muscles that some take as the indicator for a good workout. Let's make sure first that you get the most bang for your buck

Comment: Two things I want to accomplish: 1. I am getting older, and back issues are something I should watch for (the other is cardiovascular health, hence dogs). 2. I hope that, in a year or so, I can do some judo or jujitsu if my life lightens up a bit (right now I am in a temporary tight spot due to external requirements). Core is required for that. I tried in the past and their core warmup was hard enough to leave me completely washed out for the actual training.

Comment: reading through your question and comments I still can't get a grip of your goals, your means, or your current abilities. It makes the question difficult to answer

Comment: Forget about 2), you don't need to work out your core 4 times per week for a year so you can start training some Judo. It's way more efficient to start right away and be "washed up" a couple of times - given that you do some mild exercising and are not completely out of shape. 1) is interesting. Training the core can increase back issues. What makes you believe that this is the way to go and not say a back workout? I'd assume that you then have something that you want to correct with your posture. That's a great starting point, you can do stuff that specifically does that.

Comment: Most accidents I have seen were along the lines of "I was lifting this heavy shit, I slipped and now my back hurts". Training the muscles that stabilizes the torso can prevent that (hopefully) in the long term. Not only lifting, also whatever helps you when the load is uneven, or some idiot pushes it towards you when two people are carrying etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to do 3-4 *sets* per **week** of one exercise then I think you'd be better off just playing more intensely with your dogs. That's way too low of a volume to even matter. Maybe get a weighted vest when you take your dogs on a jog and you can kill two birds with one stone?

I would suggest aiming for 10 sets per muscle group per week. The types of exercises I would focus on are called *compound exercises* (think deadlifts, squats, cleans, pushups, pullups). They work out multiple muscle groups and give you the most bang for your buck. Deadlifts are probably one of the best 'core' workouts and would improve your posture and back strength. As long as you're properly warming up, using good form, and not ego lifting they're safe. Compound exercises can be done with barbells, dumbells, or bodyweight and that depends on your goals. For wellness, I think your body weight is fine to start with. I would add in weight for bigger lifts (deadlift, cleans, squats) once you're accustomed.

The reason I mentioned CrossFit is that the workouts are typically timed, use many compound movements, encourage "functional training", and they're hard; the whole community has that push yourself one more inch vibe. For example, the CrossFit workout ["Cindy"](https://wodwell.com/wod/cindy/) is:

```
AMRAP in 20 minutes
- 5 Pull-ups
- 10 Push-ups
- 15 Air squats
```

No matter what, this workout will take you 20 minutes. That's great if you're pressed for time; which it sounds like you are. You can then score yourself based on the sets completed: 11-12 (Beginner), 13-17 (Int.), 19-22 (Adv.), 24+ (Elite). This workout requires no gym, no weights, and you can do it at home with your dogs (or even in a park).

If that's too easy, the workouts can scale up ridiculously. Here's a good one called ["The Chief"](https://wodwell.com/wod/the-chief/) which, again, would only take 20 minutes:

```
AMRAP in 3 minutes
- 3 Power Cleans (135/95 lb)
- 6 Push-Ups
- 9 Air Squats
Then Rest 1 minute
Repeat 5 times
```

Answer (score 0):

I think doing one set of the plank in the morning and one set of slow and light dumbell deadlifts in the evening (almost) every day may be a possible minimum solution for the core muscles.